# Почему span не занимает всю высоту div?

Tags: html, css, html5, scss

помогите плиз, почему span не занимает весь div?

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1.5px solid #434548;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 46px;
}

span {
  display: block;
  background-color: #434548;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 46px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Запустил ваш код — всё отлично занимает, проблемы нет.

Comment: @andreymal, почему то у меня не занимает, посмотрите на кодпен, там видно что криво
https://codepen.io/colada/pen/poPWzeo

Comment: Открыл ваш кодпен, тоже всё отлично, проблемы нет https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIntx.png

Answer (score 0):

Вы там написали `1.5px` А как половину пикселя должен нарисовать браузер? В разных экранах разные размеры пикслей. Напишите `2px` и будет вам счастие.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #434548;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 46px;
}

span {
  display: block;
  background-color: #434548;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 46px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span></span>
</div>
```